# Warning: require(/home1/mokwattr/public_html/wp-includes/version.php)

Tags: php, wordpress

After migrating from old account to new account, the responds below is what i'm getting when i run the url https://mokwattrade.com/

What do i do please?

> Warning: require(/home1/mokwattr/public_html/wp-includes/version.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home1/mokwattr/public_html/wp-settings.php on line 24
>
> Warning: require(/home1/mokwattr/public_html/wp-includes/version.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home1/mokwattr/public_html/wp-settings.php on line 24
>
> Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '/home1/mokwattr/public_html/wp-includes/version.php' (include_path='.:/opt/alt/php73/usr/share/pear') in /home1/mokwattr/public_html/wp-settings.php on line 24

Comment: Do those directories exist? Does that file exist in that directory?

Comment: Always dangerous pathing a file from the root, specially when you move the site.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reference - What does this error mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php)

Comment: Yes it does, the is what i have on that line 24
require( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/version.php' );